# Any way to select from MySQL table where a field ends in certain character/number?

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping to run a mysql_query where I can select a row if a certain field ends in a number. For example:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE [ID ENDS IN 0]");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE [ID ENDS IN 1]");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE [ID ENDS IN 2]");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE [ID ENDS IN 3]");
//and so on...
?>
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using mysql_* functions anymore, because they're basically deprecated and are no longer kept up to date.  MySQLI or PDO would be a much better bet, especially as they both support parameterized queries (prepared statements) which would be a much better way of doing this than issuing multiple nearly-identical queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
  WHERE somefield LIKE '%1'
```

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: You *do* know that `LIKE` doesn't use regular expressions, right?

Comment: Depends on database. But sure in mysql this might hold true.

Comment: No, it holds true in *any variant of SQL that has `LIKE`*.

Comment: Okay think i might have mixed it up with the ~ operator in postgres (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: This is the syntax for regular expressions in MYSQL SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEXP '%0$'

Comment: You can also write it like this SELECT id FROM table WHERE id RLIKE '%0$'

Answer (score 2):

SELECT id FROM table WHERE mod(id, 10) = 1

give it a go

Comment: If you dont know whether it is numeric or string datatype, `like` is better to use as mod will only work of numeric datatypes

Comment: i made assumption if its id and it has numeric data then i would be int data-type

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
  FROM table
 WHERE id LIKE '%0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions if you need to find if field is ending in a number or not as follows

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEXP '[0-9]$'
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a cast and LIKE, but the performance is likely to be terrible for any non-trivial amount of data (I've not tested in your particular case, but in my experience, casting to string so you can use string operations really slows a query down).

A better way would be to use modulus.

For example, to get all the rows where the numerical field ends in a 4:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MOD(column_of_interest, 10) = 4
```

Again, I've not benchmarked this, but it's probably going to perform better than casting would.

Of course, if the column type is already a string, then LIKE is the way to go, as using MOD on strings would also require a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE and a wild card expression
it should be somthing like

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEX '%0$'
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEX '%1$'
```

and so on.

Comment: MySQL will automatically consider id as string if it is numeric, and will give results, so no need to cast

Comment: Isn't this behaviour dependent on MYSQL settings?

Comment: apparently for mysql LIKE can not use regular expressions like the ones i show here. Postgresql can handel that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id REGEXP '1[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: How about you add an explanation to your answer?