# How to check if exact slug (either single occurence or multiple occurence) is present in a Mysql DB?

Tags: mysql

I am creating new slug. Say my slug variable is `$slug = 'About-Us'`.

I have a table where there is a field called slug. The values of slug column can be like this:-

1. 'About-Us'
2. 'About-Us-2',
3. 'About-Us-3',
4. 'About-Us-5'

In case of duplicate slugs, we are appending a numeric value after the last dash.

1. 'About-Us-2',
2. 'About-Us-3',
3. 'About-Us-5'

When inserting new data, we need to check if a slug is either present in exact form, or the part followed by the last "-" dash is a numeric one.

I wanted to check this by using this query

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE SLUG LIKE 'About-Us%'"
```

The above query has a problem. If a slug is present like `"About-Uses"`, then it is returning a count 1. What we need to check is whether the section after the last dash is numeric or not.

Also slugs like `"About-Us-2-Know"` must be considered different from `'About-Us'`, while `'About-Us-2'` or `'About-us-3'` must be considered as multiple occurence of `'About-Us'`

EDIT:

This is not duplicate. It is not about only checking with last character as numeric. **It is about checking whether the string before last dash is exact match and string after last dash is a numeric**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql where string ends with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304308/mysql-where-string-ends-with-numbers)

Comment: This is not duplicate. **It is not about only checking with last character as numeric. It is about checking whether the string before last dash is exact match and string after last dash is a numeric**

Comment: Even the answer is the same : use regex.

Comment: And what happens if you have a look at the other answer and adapt it? Most probably, you just have to add your slug and the dash in front of ``[[:digit:]]`

Comment: The answered based on linked question: `slug = 'About-Us' OR slug REGEXP 'About-Us-[0-9]+$'` (you need to use PHP `preg_quote()` function to quote `"About-us"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved using only MySql.  May need to tweak for your needs, but using SUBSTRING_INDEX is the main solution for me.

```
/*
'About-Us'
'About-Us-2',
'About-Us-3',
'About-Us-5'
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bleach`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bleach2`;

CREATE TABLE bleach (slug VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us';
INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us-2';
INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us-3';
INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us-5';
INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us-6-extra';
INSERT INTO bleach SELECT 'About-Us-NoMatch';


-- About us match
CREATE TABLE bleach2
SELECT slug, SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug,'-',2) AS about_us,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug,'-',-1) AS  first_numeric,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(slug,'-',-2),'-',1) AS second_numeric  
FROM bleach;

SELECT * FROM bleach2;

-- All but About-Us-NoMatch should return
SELECT * FROM bleach2 WHERE about_us='About-Us' AND 
(first_numeric IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') OR second_numeric IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
OR second_numeric='About';
```

Comment: This is bad because it does not scale. Much better to use REGEXP as in the comments to the OP.

Comment: I agree the comments are the best way.  And the way I would do it. But he did not mention php.  Just trying to answer as asked.

Comment: His query is quoted though, so I guess it is implied.